# "undefined" in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, undefined

```
b

if b?
```

transforms to

```
b;

if (typeof b !== "undefined" && b !== null)
```

If I set `b = []`, I get `if (b != null) {`

Where is `undefined`? It's problem to catch undefined in array (after unique).

When I did

```
a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,444,4,4,4]
a.unique()
```

I can get something like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,444,undefined]
```

And I can't catch this, because in case `a?[key]` - I got only check for `!= null`

What I must do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem. `undefined == null` is true in JavaScript and `undefined != null` is false so `if(b != null)` covers the `b === undefined` case. Something like this:

```
a = [ undefined ]
if(a[0]?)
    console.log('if')
else
    console.log('else')
```

will produce `else` on the console as expected, so will this:

```
a = undefined
if(a?[0])
    console.log('if')
else
    console.log('else')
```

Comment: I see problem after using this function [link](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/removing-duplicate-elements-from-arrays) I've got something like ["11","12,"13","undefined"] only when I "fix" like this: `for value of output
    result.push value if value? and value != "undefined"`  I've got result without "undef.."

Comment: So you have the *string* ‘'undefined'‘ in your array?

Comment: try using string conversion.

"#{value}" instead of value when you compare with "undefined"

Comment: trying to understand - when integer value converts to string :)

Comment: @Vladislav: Can you reproduce your problem somewhere? http://jsfiddle.net/ supports CoffeeScript and coffeescript.org lets you bookmark CoffeeScript snippets.